# ¿Cómo acceder a contenido de array?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Tengo un formulario que se crea de forma dinámica, así:

```
$name_of_input = 'project-teams[' . $project_team;

    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $name_of_input; ?> => selected ]" value=""  /> <?php echo $title; ?>
```

Mi problema surge cuando quiero obtener los valores dentro del array que se ha creado; utilizado print_r('project-teams') obtengo:

```
Array ( [0] => a:1:{s:38:"ingenieria_de_iluminacion => selected";s:0:"";} ) 1
```

¿Cómo puedo acceder a "ingenieria_de_iluminacion"?

He probado con:

```
project-teams[0]['ingeniera_de_iluminacion']
```

Y este es el mensaje que recibo:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'ingenieria_de_iluminacion'
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes dentro de tu array no son otros arrays, son arrays serializados. La serialización es un proceso por el cual un valor (array, objeto o lo que sea) es transformado en una "representación de flujo de bytes" (en cristiano, una cadena). Tienes que "desserializarlos" primero antes de usarlos, de esta forma:

```
$project-teams[0] = unserialize($project-teams[0]);
```

Luego de esto, recién podrás usar `project-teams[0]['ingeniera_de_iluminacion']`  directamente